# google app script regex 3 How to remove text bounded by parenthesis?

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

I have the following text in a google document. Data text that is followed by a author, time stamp enclosed in parenthesis. The time stamps are also at the end of sentence. Some of the data text may have parenthesis also:

> Some text goes here. (John Smith; 12/20/2016 10:11 AM)
>
> More text in between the time stamps.
>
> Other text is entered here. May have several sentences. (Jane Doe; 12/20/2016
>   08:21 PM)
>
> Description of the above text (C189)

**I want to use a google app script to remove the time stamps.**

I have attempted the following regex that works in "Find and replace" menu function within google docs:

```
\(.+[AP]M\)
```

It works well in finding the time stamp: find "(", then any text that ends in "AM or "PM" followed by ")"

It also works in online regex tester.

But it does not work from within google app script:

```
function searchAndReplace() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()
  var body = doc.getBody();
  body.replaceText("\(.+[AP]M\)", "");
```

I end up with this:

> )
>
> More text in between the time stamps.
>
> )
>
> Description of the above text (C189)

I want this:

> Some text goes here.
>
> More text in between the time stamps.
>
> Other text is entered here. May have several sentences.
>
> Description of the above text (C189)

What am I doing wrong? Frustrating as the regex works within the "Find and replace" in google docs but not in the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to double escape the parenthesis as shown here.

```
function searchAndReplace() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()
  var body = doc.getBody();
  body.replaceText("\\(.+?[AP]M\\)", "");
  doc.saveAndClose();
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That is not in the RE2 Wiki.

Comment: If your issue is resolved, please accept the answer.